# how to initial a web server on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, file-sharing

i recentlly see some iPhone application which initial a web server and give a url to user, so we can access some files from that url from pc, for example an export contact app create a excel file  and for transferring that file give us a url and we can access from pc browser.

the question is how we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

These apps most likely store the data (e.g. the contact list) in the cloud and give you a URL to a frontend that uses the same cloud storage as its backend.

Answer (score 0):

A open source project named [CocoaHttpServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/wiki) can host a web server on web server on iPhone/iPad/iTouch, have a look.